# Stata xtoverid command error

Tags: stata

I have panel data and my regression is of the form:

```
s_roa1 = s_roa + c_roa
```

I am new to Stata and i am trying to use the `xtoverid` command for a `robust hausman test` to help me choose between a fixed or random effects model:

```
xtoverid s_roa1 s_roa c_roa, fe i (year)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
varlist not allowed
```

Can anyone help me understand what does this suggest?

Comment: Means what it says. You don't specify the regression variables over again. Syntax is `xtoverid [, robust cluster(varlist) ]` so at the simplest you follow your regression with just `xtoverid`. Look again at the help: no examples include variable names before the comma.

Comment: In fact, the options `fe i(year)` don't belong either. I think you're confusing different commands.

Comment: @NickCox thank you for the clarification and help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `xtoverid` is a *community-contributed* command, something which you fail to make clear in your question. It is customary and useful to provide this information right from the start, so others know that you do not refer to an official, built-in command.

Second, this is a *post-estimation* command, which means you run it **directly after** you estimate your model using `xtreg`, `xtivreg`, `xtivreg2` or `xthtaylor`.

The help file provided by the authors offers an enlightening example:

```
 . webuse nlswork
(National Longitudinal Survey.  Young Women 14-26 years of age in 1968)

 . tsset idcode year
   panel variable:  idcode (unbalanced)
    time variable:  year, 68 to 88, but with gaps
            delta:  1 unit

 . 
 . gen age2=age^2
(24 missing values generated)

 . gen black=(race==2)

 . 
 . xtivreg ln_wage age (tenure = union south), fe i(idcode)

 Fixed-effects (within) IV regression            Number of obs     =     19,007
 Group variable: idcode                          Number of groups  =      4,134

 R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
 within  =      .                                         min =          1
 between = 0.1261                                         avg =        4.6
 overall = 0.0869                                         max =         12

                                            Wald chi2(2)      =  142054.65
corr(u_i, Xb)  = -0.6875                    Prob > chi2       =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ln_wage |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
  tenure |   .2450528   .0382041     6.41   0.000     .1701741    .3199314
     age |  -.0650873   .0126167    -5.16   0.000    -.0898156    -.040359
   _cons |   2.826672   .2451883    11.53   0.000     2.346112    3.307232
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 sigma_u |  .71990151
 sigma_e |  .64315554
     rho |  .55612637   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F  test that all u_i=0:     F(4133,14871) =     1.53      Prob > F    = 0.0000
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Instrumented:   tenure
Instruments:    age union south
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 . 
 . xtoverid

 Test of overidentifying restrictions: 
 Cross-section time-series model: xtivreg fe   
 Sargan-Hansen statistic   0.965  Chi-sq(1)    P-value = 0.3259

 . xtoverid, robust

 Test of overidentifying restrictions: 
 Cross-section time-series model: xtivreg fe  robust 
 Sargan-Hansen statistic   0.960  Chi-sq(1)    P-value = 0.3271

 . xtoverid, cluster(idcode)

 Test of overidentifying restrictions: 
 Cross-section time-series model: xtivreg fe  robust cluster(idcode)
 Sargan-Hansen statistic   0.495  Chi-sq(1)    P-value = 0.4818
```

From Stata's command prompt, type `help xtoverid` for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply and help! Will make the question clearer and read the help file carefully in the future.

Comment: StataCorp now employ the expression _community-contributed_ rather than _user-written_.